# issue installing the polymer-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer, npm-install, polymer-cli

I have been trying for a few hours to get this installed now and I'm starting to think it might be an issue with the node module?
I have tried updating node, reinstalling node, updating bower, using different shells and wifi networks, installing it locally and globally.

Any other suggestions?

command: npm install -g polymer-cli

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\mb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-polymerelements-test-fixture-git-8142662e\config'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\mb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-polymerelements-test-fixture-git-8142662e\config'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm verb exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows PC make sure you are running your console (terminal) as Administrator. If using Mac OS or Linux you need to run the npm command using sudo.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to run `npm` as sudo if you've installed it as a non-root user. The error shown in the question seem unrelated to permissions.

Comment: On Windows you must run the terminal as "Administrator" for npm to install items globally "-g" flag.